# how to integrate orkut in my website through orkut api

Tags: integrate

i'm a beginner to orkut api and i don't know how to integrate orkut in my website.

I just don't know how to pass the user information to orkut server to  get the response form the orkut server.

Can u please give me the sample code for getting just the user profile and to print the display name of the given user??

thanks and regards,

yuvi

Answer (score 2):

There are also client APIs which allows you to interact directly with orkut via 3LO. With those client APIs you can send/read scraps, post photos, create albums, etc.

[The official orkut client is written in Java](http://code.google.com/p/orkut-os-client/), but the community ported it to another languages such as PHP, QT and .NET. The other links can be found in the Java client page.

Answer (score 0):

Orkut has 2 API's only:

1. Orkut API is meant to develop apps that run inside orkut.
2. [Orkut Share API](http://code.google.com/apis/orkut/docs/orkutshareapidoc.html) is the one you are looking for.